# Would a fusion reactor using Helium-3 get some of its energy from fusing it with free neutrons?

Tags: nuclear-physics, fusion, nuclear-engineering

I know that He-3-based fusion is supposed to be aneutronic, but aren't there still some free neutrons?  Would this make a noticeable difference in heat/energy produced?

Also, couldn't helium-3 be added to other neutron-producing fusion reactors to mop up the free neutron radiation?

Wouldn't that prevent the trouble caused by neutron radiation in these types of reactors?

Comment: (i) Which neutron-releasing reactions do you envisage, starting from helium-$3$ & say deuterium? (ii) For neutron blankets you want something cheap, abundant & dense, not helium-$3$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are neutrons. They come from the side-reactions. You don't use pure He3, it's a mixture of He3 and D. The D in the mixture will also undergo fusion at the same conditions, so you'll have D-D reactions giving off neutrons. So it's "less neutrons" but not "basically no neutrons" like you get from p-B11. This is ignoring neutrons from spallation events and other reactions outside the fusion itself, but these tend to be much smaller in number.

And yes, you can breed He3 using those neutrons. This is where you try to close the fuel cycle. But you'll never get nearly enough to keep the reactor going. So for every N reactors, you'll need another M other systems, perhaps D-D reactors, generating He3 for you. And the number of neutrons you need is going to mean that system is not long for the world, so you need it to be cheap and disposable.